# C# - Design Thoughts on Passing by Reference

Tags: c#, algorithm, pass-by-reference

I have a C# Windows Service that routes incoming emails and twitter comments to available `Agents` (I don't really - but the app does something very similar).  So, I have a list of `Agents`, and logic to route these emails and tweets to available agents.

How does my code look?

I have an `AgentManager` class that keeps track of which agents are available, their skill levels, etc.
I have an `EmailManager` class that routes `Emails` to `Agents`.
I have a `TwitterManager` class that routes `Tweets` to `Agents`.

So - logic pertaining to `Agents`, such as the list of `Agents`, who is available, who has capacity for a `Tweet`, who has capacity for an `Email`, etc is all in the `AgentManager`.

Now, when `EmailManager` detects that there is a new email and needs to assign it to an `Agent`, I want

to get my list of agents from `AgentManager`(rather than going back to the database or keeping a separate list of Agents in `EmailManager`).

My initial thought is to pass `AgentManager` to `EmailManager` by reference.  The reason I want to do this is so as Agents change state, are added/removed, etc - `EmailManager` will always be working wit

h the latest `AgentManager` (and therefore the latest Agent list).  Somehow - this feels dirty.  I know it is out of fashion to pass by ref, but it seems to be a good way to handle this.  Am I doing it wrong?

**EDIT:**
I am passing the AgentManager by reference for storage, not to change it in the EmailManager class.

Comment: Are you *passing by reference*, or *storing a reference*. Very different things, but it sounds like you're storing a reference (i.e. the email manager stores a pointer to the agent manager). Might be worth rewording the question for more clarity.

Comment: If AgentManager is a class, you're going to have to jump through some hoops to NOT pass it by reference.  I mean, you're basically describing the same thing as a long-lifespan context used by EF, right?

Comment: I am passing by reference for storage only, correct.

Comment: @Alex: Agreed. Stuff in C# is passed by reference more often than not. Are you saying you'd create an EmailManager(AgentManager manager) constructor?

Comment: But AgentManager is a reference type, therefore you would be passing it by reference just by passing it. You only need to specify "ref" keyword when you want to edit something that doesn't event have to be a reference type.

Comment: @DejanJanjušević Ok - that seems to be the overriding theme in the responses I am seeing.  I probably should have known that, honestly.  Thanks!

Comment: In addition, [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) provides a better undestanding on parameter passing in C#.

Comment: @Killnine - "Are you saying you'd create an EmailManager(AgentManager manager) constructor?" - Wasn't really offering a solution, just suggesting the question might want rewording. "Design Thoughts on Passing by Reference" is pretty vague and meaningless, certainly not what the OP was trying to attract answers for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your descriptions seems more soud to go the other way.
An AgentManager process EMails and Tweets and knows everything of its Agents -
So it should have a method that receive a list of EMails/Tweets and process them.

Because we are speaking of reference-types the question about passing by ref is a bit unclear.

For example:

```
AgentManager ag = new AgentManager();
EMailManager eg = new EMailManager();
TweetManaget tg = new TweetManager();

eg.LoadEMail();
List<EMails> mails = eg.GetMailsList();

tg.LoadTweet();
List<Tweets> tws = tg.GetTweetsList();

ag.ProcessData(mails, tws);
```

EDIT: Looking at the comment from OP I have thought of another strategy
Let the EMailManager and TweetManager declare an Event to which the AgentManager subscribe-

```
eg.EmailReceived += ag.NotifyEmail;
tg.TweetPolled += ag.NotifyTweet;


public class EventManager
{
    public delegate void OnMailReceived(EMails m);
    public event MailReceived;

    ........

    private void GetMail()
    {
        EMails m;
        .....
        if(MailReceived != null) 
            MailReceived(m);
    }
}

public class AgentManager()
{
     public void NotifyEMail(EMails m)
     {
         .....
     }


}
```

Comment: I like this idea, it makes more sense in my opinion. Is there anything else about the EmailManager that might make this problematic?

Comment: EmailManager and TweetManager are both long running processes that will work indepentendly of eachother. Unfortunately I can't set it up as straightforward as you have above (I would like to), but Emails come in in real time where as Tweets are "polled". Both of these operate on their own - only sharing the need to know which agents are "available".  I guess I could queue up all events and process them at once to achieve something similar to above?

Comment: Steve - I really like this idea.  Thanks!